# Converting shapefiles to GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, convert

I'm trying to convert shapefiles from the [State of Texas Senate Districts](http://www.tlc.state.tx.us/redist/districts/senate.html) website into a GeoJSON file for use with Google Maps API.

I'm using QGIS to facilitate but I can't get the projection/coordinates right. So far I've tried Google Mercator (EPSG:900913) and WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) with no luck.

I'm using the OpenLayers to verify results and it keeps placing Texas near the  Gulf of Guinea (0 lat, 0 lng).

Answer (score 26):

It is no problem to load the downloadable shapefile directly into QGIS.

The data is in EPSG:3081, you better leave it that way. Google API expects latlong values, so the target CRS should be EPSG:4326.

Just rightclick on the layer -> Save As... to choose file type GeoJSON, a different file name, and EPSG:4326 as new CRS. You can add the result to the canvas to see that they align (`On-the-fly-reprojection`selected).

Comment: any way to "save as" with multiple layers?

Comment: No, every file needs a different destination file name. You can use ogr2ogr on the command line for batch processing.

Comment: seems like maybe the batch processing support, which supports things like sensible defaults for automatic file naming could be employed to just send the resulting files to a folder

Answer (score 10):

Via Command line:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 output.geojson input.shp
```

I guess this is what the web client from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91816/70242) uses.

Comment: Just tested. Behaves way better than QGIS when it comes to the RAM consumption!

Answer (score 9):

Here is the convert tool for shapefile to geojson via web browser without server-side code and supporting non-english encoding, just need to upload the zip file and set the encoding for the correctly text.

https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js

If you use this library with Google Map api v3, you can skip EPSG code field because the ZIP archive(PlanS172.zip) download form [the State of Texas Senate Districts website](http://www.tlc.state.tx.us/redist/districts/senate.html) contain the .prj file.

```
loadshp({
    url: '/shp/PlanS172.zip', // path or your upload file
    encoding: 'big5' // default utf-8
}, function(geojson) {
    // geojson returned
});
```

[image]

Comment: This helped me upload a geojson file to MapBox. I tried using QGIS 2.18.16, but MapBox threw an error about a deprecated EPSGI:4236 tag in the first line.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you if you only need to do a few shapefiles

http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

Comment: thats pretty nice, I was about to send a link with ogr2ogr example

Answer (score 0):

How about trying out this online tool?

https://9revolution9.com/en/tools/geo/shp_geojson/

[image: https://9revolution9.com/en/tools/geo/shp_geojson/]