# Where to find GeoJSON data for the UK?

Tags: data, geojson, united-kingdom

I want to get GeoJSON data for the UK. The regions which I require are in the map displayed in the below link:
[Former Government Office regions](http://www.apho.org.uk/resource/view.aspx?RID=50213)

I have been searching the net but all in vain. Can anyone help?

Comment: have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91812/convert-shapefiles-to-geojson and see if that helps

Comment: If your comfortable with using the command line, this tutorial may help you create the GeoJSON file yourself http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Answer (score 6):

Geographic data are rarely distributed as GeoJson files. If you need to do some search, you should rather enter "download shapefile" as key words. For the UK, you can find free administrative boundaries on the [Ordnance survey](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products-grid.html) website or on [GDAM](http://www.gadm.org/download).

Once you have your shapefile, you can convert it to Geojson using different software. For instance, you can use Python (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41465/generating-geojson-with-python)) or QGIS (Layer > save layer as... GeoJson).

I've also found an [online converter](http://techslides.com/demos/mapping/shapefile-geojson-converter.html) but did not test it.