# Looking for world maritime boundaries in Geojson

Tags: data, geojson, boundaries, maritime-map

I would like to use leaflet in order to display the world maritime boundaries (12 nm and 24 nm). Is there a reliable geojson source that I could use? If no geojson data is available, I am ready to use any other data format as long as I can convert it to geojson.

Comment: If you are seeking open data the place to ask would be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

A web search turned up [this download site](http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php) for world maritime boundaries as an ESRI shapefile.  Here are directions for converting the shapefile to geojson [using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91812/convert-shapefiles-to-geojson/94960) and [here for ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-conversion-toolbox.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use data from the [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) project.

[OpenStreetMapData](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines) is a good source. The data has been derived from OpenStreetMap ways tagged with *natural=coastline*. The data is offered as a shapefile. [There are a lot of ways](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91812/convert-shapefiles-to-geojson) to convert shapefiles to GeoJSON.